# How to update BsonArray values in a BsonDocument with C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, mongodb, updates

I save objects into MongoDB documents having a structure with several nested documents and arrays containing documents. Considering I make some updates into these objects, I want to push them into their relatives documents in DB.
The goal here is to do it in an atomic way.

Non atomic way is what I manage to do. Example: If I want to update some values of documents contained in an array, no problem, I just update the whole array =>

```
Current_WantedBets[Cpt_Wanted].Event.Market.m_Players[PlayerProperties.Cpt].
p_Cycles.Add(new WantedDoc.EventClass.MarketClass.PlayerClass.CycleClass());

Current_WantedBets[Cpt_Wanted].Event.Market.m_Players[PlayerProperties.Cpt].
p_Cycles[CycleProperties.Cpt].c_CurrentLane = "Just an example";

Current_WantedBets[Cpt_Wanted].Event.Market.m_Players[PlayerProperties.Cpt].
p_Cycles[CycleProperties.Cpt].c_TimeStart = DateTimeOffset.Now;

Current_WantedBets[Cpt_Wanted].Event.Market.m_Players[PlayerProperties.Cpt].
p_Cycles[CycleProperties.Cpt].c_TimeEnd = DateTimeOffset.Now;

CycleProperties.c_Index_ThisEvent += 1;

filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("_id", Current_WantedBets[Cpt_Wanted].Id);

var update = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update
.Set("Event.Market.m_Players." + PlayerProperties.p_Position + ".p_Cycles",
Current_WantedBets[Cpt_Wanted].Event.Market.m_Players[PlayerProperties.Cpt].p_Cycles);

MatchbookStorage.DBContext.collections[MatchbookStorage.COL_CURRENT_WANTEDBETS].
UpdateOne(filter, update);
```

Here, in my object, p_Cycles is a list of objects and it's an array of documents in DB. The problem here I can make just one or two updates in a complex object and to reflect this back to the db, I update the whole big array...this is not an atomic approach.

My try to have an atomic approach fails, it looks like :

```
update = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update
       .Set("Event.Market.m_Players." + PlayerProperties.p_Position +
 ".p_Cycles[" + CycleProperties.Cpt + "].c_CurrentLane", "test")

       .Set("Event.Market.m_Players." + PlayerProperties.p_Position + 
".p_Cycles[" + CycleProperties.Cpt + "].c_TimeStart",
XmlConvert.ToString(DateTimeOffset.Now))

       .Set("Event.Market.m_Players." + PlayerProperties.p_Position + 
".p_Cycles[" + CycleProperties.Cpt + "].c_TimeEnd",
XmlConvert.ToString(DateTimeOffset.Now));

MatchbookStorage.DBContext.collections[MatchbookStorage.COL_CURRENT_WANTEDBETS].
UpdateOne(filter, update);
```

CycleProperties.Cpt is an integer here.

The problem here is, instead of having my updates in the array `p_Cycles` in the related bsondocument, it created, next to the array, a nested bsondocument called `p_Cycles[0]`

Would you know how to make these updates in the nested documents of an array without updating the whole array?